# Return an int result from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

So I want to find the max ID and return it by adding 1.

The following is my code in SQLhelper. It looks so wrong because its public void in but i returned CR. Im a little bit confused since cursor is used to read records, but i only want the result of integer to be returned using the SQL query.

```
 public int getID( String name){
    String idquery="SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id),0)+1 FROM "+TableInfo.TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE appliance="+name;
    SQLiteDatabase SQ=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor CR=SQ.rawQuery(idquery,null);
    return CR;
}
```

This is how i call it from another activity

```
int no_id=DB.getID(name);
```

Someone please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Before your return, access the cursor to check if there is any row. If there is, access the first column to retrieve your ID by CR.getInt(0), assume its the only column so it will be index 0. Return that retrieved value instead of the entire cursor.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do like:

```
public int getID( String name){

    String idquery="SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id),0)+1 FROM "+TableInfo.TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE appliance="+name;

    SQLiteDatabase SQ=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor CR=SQ.rawQuery(idquery,null);


     int id = -1;

     if (CR != null && CR.getCount() > 0) {
         CR.moveToFirst();
         id = CR.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(YOUR_COLUMN_NAME));
         CR.close();
     }
     return id;
}
```

**Edited:**

Change your column [alias](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_alias_syntax.htm) in query **`IFNULL(MAX(id),0)+1`** like **`IFNULL(MAX(id),0)+1 as maxcount`** then you can give it while taking value from cursor:

```
id = CR.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("maxcount"));
```

and it will return Integer as you want.

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: what does this line do 'id = CR.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(YOUR_COLUMN_NAME));'? because the returned result don have any column.

Comment: Take `IFNULL(MAX(id),0)+1 as maxcount` and give it as column name,

Comment: so meaning i have a column named maxcount which take the `IFNULL(MAX(id),0)+1`? can i just smply execute the query and take its value into the function?

Comment: Yeah,,, and that you have to pass as a column name.

Comment: can i just smply execute the query and take its value into the function?

Comment: @whoami Its simply like a function. you have to do it like this only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111907/discussion-between-pratik-butani-and-whoami).

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
public int getMaxID(){
    int maxID = 0;

    String selectQuery = "SELECT "+here you primary key name +" FROM " + TableInfo.TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do{
            maxID = cursor.getInt(0);

        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return cursor.getCount();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `name` is a string value, you must quote it in SQL. But a better way would be to use a parameter.

To read a single number from a query without having to muck around with a cursor, there is a useful [helper function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#longForQuery%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29):

```java
int getID(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    return (int)DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db,
            "SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id),0)+1"+
            " FROM "+TableInfo.TABLE_NAME+
            " WHERE appliance=?",
            new String[]{ name });
}
```